# ReLU Prime with NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to pass a multidimensionnal array into the *relu* `prime` function

```
def reluprime(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

... where the `x` is the whole array. It returns

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I've had this problem with the normal `relu` function, and instead of using the python function `max()` I used `np.max()` and it worked. But with the relu prime, it is not working either way. I tried:

```
def reluprime(x):
    if np.greater(x, 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

... and it still returned the same error. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Your issue here is that the `if` statement does not work for vectorized code. The `>` operator is fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The if statement does not make sense since it is only evaluated once, for the whole array. If you want the equivalent of an if statement for each element of the array, you should do something like:

```
def reluprime(x):
    return np.where(x > 0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: This is about 3x slower than Miriam's answer, but is indeed the most natural vectorization of the original code, and in general is the right approach to translating `if` statements.

Answer (score 9):

Since relu prime returns 1 if an entry in a vector is bigger than 0 and 0 otherwise, you could just do:

```
def reluprime(x):
    return (x>0).astype(x.dtype)
```

in the code above, the input array `x` is assumed to be a numpy array.
For example, `reluprime(np.array([-1,1,2]))` returns `array([0, 1, 1])`.

Comment: `astype(x.dtype)` is likely more useful here

Comment: @Eric, thank, that makes sense! I modified the answer.

Comment: Since in a machine learning context, you'll typically using `float32` or `float64`, and will want an output of the same precision

Answer (score 4):

"relu prime", or the gradient of the ReLU function, is better known as the "heaviside step function".

Numpy 1.13 introduces a `ufunc` for this:

```
def reluprime(x):
    return np.heaviside(x, 0)
    # second value is value at x == 0
    # note that ReLU is not differentiable at x==0, so there is no right value to
    # pass here
```

Timing results on my machine show this to perform pretty poorly, suggesting more work is needed there:

```
In [1]: x = np.random.randn(100000)

In [2]: %timeit np.heaviside(x, 0)  #mine
1.31 ms ± 58.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit np.where(x > 0, 1.0, 0.0)  # Jonas Adler's
658 µs ± 74.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit (x>0).astype(x.dtype)  # Miriam Farber's
172 µs ± 34.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```